# R: Question about using lapply() function instead of for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I have been running the following for loop function with success:

```
for (i in 1:10){
   X=get(paste0("Y_lines",i))
   X <- tm_map(X, content_transformer(tolower))
   assign(paste0("Y_lines",i), X)
rm(X)}
```

I would like to use a lapply() function instead as it is much more time-efficient. I have played around with the function but not found any success. This was my most recent effort:

```
lapply(X = Y_lines[1:10], FUN = tm_map(X, content_transformer(tolower)))
```

This is my first time using lapply, so apologies if I have made basic errors.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: X in your `for` loop is initialized to the atomic character "Y_lines1", Y_lines2", etc.  X in your lapply function suggests a vector named `Y_lines` indexed from 1 to 10.  i.e. `Y_lines[1], Y_lines[2]...`  If `Y_lines` is a vector, in your loop `X = Y_lines[i]` and in your `lapply` function, `lapply(Y_lines, ...).  The `lapply` function will implicitly loop through Y_lines.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The answer below seemed to have worked, but as suggested, I will also try this method and see the outcomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a crack, note this is untested and you may need to insert a `setNames()` function between the `list2env()` and `lapply()` functions: (edit in line with additional question):
We can store the result of the first part of the anonymous function and then apply another function on it like so:

```
list2env(lapply(mget(ls(.GlobalEnv, pattern = "Y_lines"), envir = .GlobalEnv), function(x){
    y <- tm_map(x, content_transformer(tolower))
    tm_map(y, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
  }
), .GlobalEnv)
```

OR we can function overload:

```
list2env(lapply(mget(ls(.GlobalEnv, pattern = "Y_lines"), envir = .GlobalEnv), function(x){
    tm_map(tm_map(x, content_transformer(tolower)), removeWords, stopwords("english"))
  }
), .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! Out of curiosity, is it possible to apply multiple functions at once?

Comment: @VladimirTech31. Yes it is, inside the anonymous function you can even store locally scoped variables and operate them etc.

Comment: I tried adding a new line within the lapply braces with a couple separate functions but it only ran the last function. Could you provide an example of how multiple functions would look like?

Comment: @VladimirTech31 sorry for the late response, see above.